# How to Solve unknown_ca error on WSO2IS-5.7 when using MySQL RDS as backstore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wso2, amazon-rds, wso2-identity-server

I've tried to install an instance on AWS using aws RDS as 
my datasource through the mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar
with jdbc url

jdbc:mysql://< instance>.< zone>.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/carbon_db

i've got an exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failurecom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 7 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 7 milliseconds ago.
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    .
    .
    .
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

I've tried to run

```
keytool -importcert -keystore <keystore> -storepass <pass> -noprompt -file rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

on cacerts.jks in JVM and client-trustore.jks inside WSO2 repository with no effect

Answer (score 2):

This happens since the public certificate from your DB connection, is not trusted by the WSO2 Identity Server.

Since you have tried adding the certificate, verify whether this has been added properly.

1. Get the public certificate from your DB instance.
2. Go to the `<IS_HOME>/repository/resources/security` folder. Import the public certificate to the client-truststore.jks file. Use the command below.

`keytool -importcert -file certificate.cer -keystore client-truststore.jks -alias "Alias"`

Restart the wso2 IS instance and check if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MySQL connector documentation in [[1]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), following JDBC URL parameters should be included into the JDBC url to enable the SSL communication between MySQL server and the wso2 server.

```
useSSL=true
requireSSL=true
clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl
clientCertificateKeyStorePassword
```

I was able to successfully create the secure connection between MySQL server and the wso2 server with the below JDBC URL.

```
jdbc:mysql://<HOST_NAME>:<PORT>/apimgtdb?useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:<WSO2_HOME>/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks&amp;clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=wso2carbon
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@bajpushpakumara/securing-mysql-connection-and-connecting-wso2-servers-7f053122419